# How to convert my Fedora Linux system from BIOS to UEFI

Tags: linux, grub2, uefi

I'm changing my BIOS boot Fedora system to UEFI. I was following the guide here:

[How to convert an Arch Linux system from BIOS to UEFI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557325/how-to-convert-an-arch-linux-system-from-bios-to-uefi)

I have /dev/sda1 as a 1GB /boot partition. This has flags "boot" and is ext4. See the image here:

[image]

The guide says to convert to UEFI I need:

```
- "EFI System" partition with type EF00, VFat formatted, and mounted at /boot/efi
- A small Linux partition, mounted at /boot
```

efibootmgr -v
gives
"EFI variables are not supported on this system."

What would I have to do to change my partitions to match this - please be specific with commands, as I'm fairly new to this I have got a bit lost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your partition scheme is MBR while EFI boot requires GPT.

I would suggest enabling EFI in BIOS and booting from a Fedora install disk or System Rescue. Then you could use `gdisk` to convert MBR to GPT but you'll still need an EFI system partition which you're currently missing. You can free some space with `gdisk` and create a partition. Then you'll have to install `grub2-efi` and `grub2-tools-efi`.

Comment: Thanks. To free some space, would I re-partition /dev/sda1 (the boot partition) and have another EFI VFat formatted partition? If so, how would I do this and how big should it be?

Comment: 200MB is more than enough for the EFI system partition.

Comment: What would be the gdisk command to create this EFI partition?

Comment: Use gparted instead. It has UI and it's quite straightforward.

Comment: I think the gparted command erases drive. You do have good backups? Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html Note that you will have to totally reinstall grub as it changes from the BIOS version to the UEFI version. And may have to update other UUIDs in fstab as they will change.  Often easier to just reinstall & restore data & configuration from backups.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/bios-uefi gives a complete guide to doing it for Fedora.